# Security group maintenance across site collection

Tags: groups

Has anyone found another solution to AD for group maintenance across sites? Thanks in advance.

We don't have the option of AD to sync groups across site collections. Although most groups are confined to their own site collection, we do have a large number of groups which need to be reused across a number of collections.

For sizing issues - we've had to partition e.g. a specific business function across a few sites, but they have groups in common. We currently have the prospect of having to manually synchronise groups across sites e.g  add new user to the same 'Project Manager' group in three sites.

In addition, to cross site collaboration, sites will be replicated to ring-fence active and archive material, with same groups duplicated across both. Replication again - down to sizing limitations ruling out Records Management in place.

Appreciate any steer.